# Using variables from outside classes inside classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 files:

variables.py:

```
global var
var = 'test'
```

and main.py:

```
import variables

class functionsclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.testfunction()


    def testfunction(self):
        print(variables.var)

functionsclass()
```

that does not work, because 'variables.var' doesn't point to 'test'.
What do I have to write to access the variable 'var'?
I don't want to use a parameter, I just want to access the global variable.

**Edit: Sorry. I'm dumb. In my original file I set the wrong var to global, that's why I could not access it.**

Cheers

Comment: This works for me. Make sure that `main.py` is in the same directory as `variables.py`?

Comment: What is the error you are observing? Do you get a traceback?

Comment: Sorry. I'm dumb. In my original file I set the wrong var to global, that's why I could not access it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your repro, and it works fine for me both with `python2` and `python3`.  The `global` keyword actually does [something different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) and is not needed, but doesn't hurt.

[Also, FWIW I'd recommand using new-style classes, e.g. `class functionsclass(object):`]

Comment: Sorry. I'm dumb. In my original file I set the wrong var to global, that's why I could not access it.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried your code and it did work for me :- successfully printed "test". I don't see anything wrong due to which your code is not running.

It might sound dumb, but just check whether the two files (`variables.py` and `main.py`) are in the same directory. Because, keeping those two files in separate directory can make it inaccessible.

And, could you please try with the following modifications to your `main.py` file and check whether this works :-

```
from variables import var

class functionsclass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.testfunction()


    def testfunction(self):
        print(var)

functionsclass()
```